# Why does React add '.$' to the start of a key

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have react component that renders something like:

```
<div>
    <div key='bowie'>something</div>
<div>
```

when I query the keys of each node (using enzyme if that matters), my keys are printed as

```
.$bowie
```

Is the `.$` something I can rely on? What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

It is not something you can rely on. The key attribute does not give any public API beside the original assignment, and the value is only used internally to improve the rendering/diffing algorithm.

React v15+ actually removed the data-reactid attribute (I'm assuming this is where you are seeing the keys?) from the DOM entirely, since it now uses internal references. [More on that in the React 15 release blog post.](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html#major-changes)

As far as the importance of the `$` itself, I'm not sure, but I would guess that it made it easier to parse the IDs.